# How to provide uWSGI multiple static-map options through environment variable?

Tags: options, uwsgi

[uWSGI manual](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StaticFiles.html) on static files serving states that:

> You can specify multiple `--static-map` options, even for the same
> mountpoint.
>
> `--static-map /images=/var/www/img --static-map /images=/var/www/img2 --static-map /images=/var/www/img3`
>
> The file will be searched in each directory until it’s found, or if it’s not,
> the request will be managed by your app.

I'm looking for a way to pass multiple options through env var like this:

```
UWSGI_STATIC_MAP="/images/=/var/www/img1/"
UWSGI_STATIC_MAP="/images/=/var/www/img2/"
UWSGI_STATIC_MAP="/images/=/var/www/img3/"
```

but, of course, var values will be overwritten, so there must be some syntax for one-shot declaration (or not).

[Documentation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html#environment-variables) about configuring uWSGI via env vars is rather scarce and most information I found is in this [tutorial on caktusgroup.com](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2017/03/14/production-ready-dockerfile-your-python-django-app/), which states that *"uWSGI is almost entirely configurable through environment variables"*.

Any help/hint appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've finally found in [the documentation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html#environment-variables) the one sentence I was looking for:

> Several values for the same configuration variable are not supported with this method.